# When does -Contains not work and/or should I use something else

Tags: powershell

If I have two arrays of information. One massive and the other much smaller.

```
$lista ="1,2,3,4,5...etc for a lot "
$listb ="1,9,11"  (Much smaller)

If ($listA -contains $listB){
Do stuff
}
```

Does this make sense and work?

It seems to me like it doesn't always work and I am having trouble double checking it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Containment Operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators#containment-operators) are ideal for your use case, however, you're trying to compare an *array* against another *array* and that wouldn't work, these operators can help you identify if an *element* (a scalar, single value)  exists in an array.

Both pairs (`-in` / `-notin`) and (`-contains` / `-notcontains`) should be equally efficient, the only difference is where the scalar is placed, for the first pair the scalar is on the **left-hand side** of the operation whereas for the later the scalar is on the **right-hand side**.

Taken from the Docs to helps us give some perspective to the explanation:

```
<Collection> -contains <Test-object>
<Collection> -notcontains <Test-object>
<Test-object> -in <Collection>
<Test-object> -notin <Collection>
```

As for your current code, that would require a loop, likely over the *small array*. **Why?**

> These operators **stop comparing** as soon as they detect the **first match**, whereas the equality operators evaluate all input members. In a very large collection, these operators return quicker than the equality operators.

Following that logic, you could loop over your *small array* and add the comparison, this is up to you which one is more readable for you. Your code could look like this:

```
$lista = 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
$listb = 2,4,6,8,10

foreach($item in $listb)
{
    if($item -in $lista) {
        $item
        # Do something here
    }
}
```

There might be use cases where a [`HashSet<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1?view=net-6.0) can be very useful, for example, if we want to get unique values out of `$lista` (in this case, we want **case-insensitive** hence the use of  out of [**StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase Property**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.stringcomparer.ordinalignorecase?view=net-6.0#system-stringcomparer-ordinalignorecase) on it's constructor)  and see which values are also contained on `$listb`, in this case probably we would want to use the [`.Contains(..)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1.contains?view=net-6.0#system-collections-generic-hashset-1-contains(-0)) or [`.IntersectWith(..)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1.intersectwith?view=net-6.0#system-collections-generic-hashset-1-intersectwith(system-collections-generic-ienumerable((-0)))) or [`.ExceptWith(..)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1.exceptwith?view=net-6.0) methods of this class instead of the operators.

```
$lista = 'A','x','y','z','a','B','b','C','c'
$listb = 'a','B','c'

$hashset = [System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[string]]::new(
    [string[]]$lista,
    [System.StringComparer]::OrdinalIgnoreCase
)

# To find the elements of `$listB` present in `$hashset`
foreach($item in $listb)
{
    if($hashset.Contains($item)) {
        $item
    }
}

# The other way around, find the elements of `$hashset`
# present in `$listb`
$hashset.IntersectWith([string[]]$listb)
$hashset

# And the opposite, elements of `$hashset` NOT present in `$listb`
$hashset.ExceptWith([string[]]$listb)
$hashset
```